# search an array for a value match and replace value - php

Tags: php, arrays

Thanks for your help i'm stuck on this problem. Let me explain it, i have this kind of array.

```
First Array
--------------
Array
(
    [2] => value7
    [3] => value8
    [4] => value9
    [5] => value10
    [6] => value11
    [7] => value12
    [8] => value13
)
```

```
Second Array
--------------
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 7
        )
)
```

and Desired result :
( if second array value == first array key; change second array value )

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => value10
            [1] => value8
            [2] => value11
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => value13
            [1] => value9
            [2] => value12
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we suppose that your `arrays` are like these :

```
$array1 = array(
     2 => 'value7',
     3 => 'value8',
     4 => 'value9',
     5 => 'value10',
     6 => 'value11',
     7 => 'value12',
); 
$array2 = array(
    array(
        10 => 5,
        1 => 7,
        2 => 4,
     ),
    array(
        0 => ''
    ),
    array(
        0 => 3
    )    
);
```

Then this will do the job :

```
$keys1 = array_keys($array1);
foreach($array2 as $innerKey => $innerArray) {
    foreach($innerArray as $k => $val) {
        if(in_array($val, $keys1)) {
            $array2[$innerKey][$k] = $array1[$val];
        }
    }
}
var_dump($array2);
```

**output** :

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      10 => string 'value10' (length=7)
      1 => string 'value12' (length=7)
      2 => string 'value9' (length=6)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'value8' (length=6)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you displayed you Arrays correctly. Does this answer your question?

```
foreach($secondArray as $i => $v){
  if($firstArray[$v])$secondArray[$i] = $firstArray[$v];
}
```